# Consume Post API Service From C#

Tags: c#

I have a link for API Service with token. This service inserts list of records from my database to another database.
I retrieved a list of some items, and want to consume the API rest service by using this list and the token given.
This service takes a JSON object to insert, and return a result of insert.
Is there any sample of C# code doing the same?

Comment: Sounds like the `HttpClient` class is what you're looking for.  There are many examples on Google to get you started.

Comment: You'll want to use a json library like Newtonsoft/Json.net/Utf8Json and then the HttpClient. Give it an attempt and then show us what you tried

Comment: what have you googled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you'll have to use a JSON serializer which will convert your list to JSON format and then pass it to the web service using any of the available .NET web clients.

Have a look at the below code snippet:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;

namespace MyNamespace
{

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //your input list
            List<string> animals = new List<string> { "Dog", "Cat", "Mouse" };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(animals);
            //call your web API by passing this JSON along with your token
            CallWebService(json);
        }

        private static void CallWebService(string requestPayload)
        {
            string url = "your webservice URL";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.ContentLength = requestPayload.Length;
            StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
            requestWriter.Write(requestPayload);
            requestWriter.Close();

            try
            {
                WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
                Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
                StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
                string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.Out.WriteLine(response);
                responseReader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine("-----------------");
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
     }
}
```

**Note**: I've referenced newtonsoft NuGet package in my project.

Comment: Thanks Anki For your help, but how can i pass the token to the services? it's responses every time with unauthorized.